# How to force controller/action to use JsonValueProvider

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Good day!

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 where [JsonValueProvider](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) is built-in.

The problem is that it works only if `Content-Type: application/json` specified.

I'm building an API where JSON is the only supported format and I don't want to force clients setting this header.

Is there any way to force controller/action to use particular ValueProvider?

Comment: I know this is not really an answer but say a few months down the line someone says, 'oh can I have the result in XML' then you will have to say no (go away)!! Might be worth keeping it more flexible and open to other formats. (also then your problem automagically goes away)

Comment: I really like to support the broadest range of formats (at least have the possibility to do so), but content-type header can be a problem to set up by 70% of consumers of my API.

Comment: I see what you mean and it must be very annoying! Just say to them, "oi, if you can't set a content-type header, then what the hell are doing using an API??" ;-)

Comment: That's not a limitation of programmers, that's limitation of platform they use. But I will investigate myself is this really a problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this works and is very simple, it seems more of a hack. What you can do is create an attribute deriving from `AuthorizeAttribute` and in `OnAuthorization` you set the Content-Type to application/json.

```
public class JsonActionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType = "application/json";
    }
}

[JsonAction]
public ActionResult JsonOnlyAction(string var1, int var2, ...)
{
    ...
}
```

This attribute can also be applied at the controller level.

Originally I tried setting the Content-Type in an action filter but the problem is `OnActionExecuting` occurs *after* value providers are selected so setting the content-type there is too late.

`OnAuthorization` occurs *before* value providers are selected, and since the `JsonValueProviderFactory` checks for `Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json")` this will ensure it's selected.

Comment: Nice hack, I'll mark it as answer if someone not come up with more framework-oriented approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I'm misunderstanding the question, but isn't this what you need to do:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
```

You can create an action filter/attribute to avoid repeating this line in multiple actions.

Comment: Nope, the question about incoming requests -- I'd like to force ASP.NET to interpret request as JSON-encoded.