# Native attribute to force controller/action to accept JSON for MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 would like to force the content-type to application/json by default for the action. Is there any way to force controller/action to use JSON?

NOTE: There was an [answer but regarding MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036017/how-to-force-controller-action-to-use-jsonvalueprovider). Has there been anything released in MVC4 that is native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has not been anything new added to MVC 4 that changes the answer given for MVC 3. Sorry.